# Text field and tabs becomes wider while fetching results in Users search

Tags: bug, search, user-interface

Whenever I add some text to search for users, the text field and the tabs on the right becomes unexpectedly wider.

[image: GIF]

I'm using Firefox 72 and Chrome 79 on Ubuntu 18.04.